# file is being imported as a list within a list - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to import a csv file into python. For some reason however for this particular file imports as a list within a list, ie the numbers are correct but its in double square brackets. I can't figure out how to stop this

```
with open ('frequencies.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')

    frequencies = [column for column in reader]
```

> [['40', '45', '50', '55', '60']]

I would like it to import as a regular list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put it like this then: `frequencies = column for column in reader`, without the `[ ]`

Comment: You're looping over rows, not columns.

Comment: The items you get by iterating over `reader` are *rows*, not columns.  If there's only one column in each row, `[row[0] for row in reader]` would work.

Comment: If there's only one column, what's the point of using `csv`?

Comment: @BokiX That's equivalent to `frequencies = list(reader)`

Comment: No, that's a syntax error.

Comment: without the square brackets is a syntax error

Comment: @Barmar it does the same thing

Comment: It looks like your csv file is just one _row_. You could just do `frequencies = next(reader)`. Please note that you are expected to provide a [mre] when asking on Stack Overflow. This means your example must be _minimal_ (remove anything irrelevant to your problem) and _reproducible_ (we must be able to run it on our computers with the information you've given). Your example isn't reproducible because we don't know what your input file looks liek

Comment: @Barmar Depends on whether you *know* how many columns are in the file ahead of time.